# Creating Python WPS in GeoServer

Tags: python, geoserver, wps

I try to create a custom Python WPS in my GeoServer instance.

I follow this guidance : https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/scripting/py/index.html#wps
but GeoServer doesn't see my new WPS.

Steps :

- fresh intance of GeoServer 2.18.3 with tomcat
- create `scripts/wps`directory in my GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR
- create file `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/scripts/wps/buffer.py`
- Copy/Paste the example code in the previous link
- Restart GeoServer
- Run a GetCap' on WPS service
- Cannot find my buffer service.

Have I forgotten a step for doing this like adding a extension ?

I try do to the same with a `java` wps script (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implementing.html) and this work.

But if I can, I prefer to make my WPS in Python code.

Comment: I think the scripts extension was "retired" sometime last year. it looks like we're aren't deleting old files in the documentation, as those pages are a version out of date and are not linked to anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script extension has been retired from GeoServer, as it did not have a maintainer any longer.

See: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9871

We just need a new maintainer to show up and dust off the old code, then it can be added back to GeoServer.