# Geoserver WPS Error: No such process: py:my_script

Tags: python, geoserver, wps

I have several python process scripts, all of them are stored in the folder **wps** under the next tree structure:

**my_app/

├─ geoserver/

│  ├─ data/

│  │  ├─ scripts/

│  │  │  ├─ wps/

│  │  │  │  ├─ my_script.py

│  │  │  │  ├─ my_script2.py

│  │  │  │  ├─ my_script3.py**

Even if the processes scripts are found by the `GeoServer Demos WPS request builder`, after `Execute Process` I get the error:

```
py:my_script this script yields to something.No such process: py:my_script
```

The directory permissions of the **wps** folder and the scripts are:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root ...
```

I have tried setting up all permissions to the files `wps.xml` and `global.xml`, as well as activate and verify the `WPS Security and input limits` for each of the scripts, and of course restart the `GeoServer` but is still unsuccessful.

Ps: In fact two weeks ago the scripts were well recognized and executed.

How could I solve this error ?

Comment: Since you code in Python, why not give a try to [PyWPS](https://pywps.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

Can't serve python scripts as WPS through geoserver anymore.

[Previous question here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427457/creating-python-wps-in-geoserver)

You can still serve [scripts written in Java](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implementing.html) as WPS.

[pygeoapi](https://github.com/geopython/pygeoapi) implements (or helps you to implement) the newest OGC standards while programming in python.

Comment: The plugging was removed the last year, and my scripts were being well recognized and executed two weeks ago, since I’ve not performed any update of the Geoserver, so I don’t know how it just stop to work…